# How to configure Jenkins to send emails?

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I'm trying to configure Jenkins to send out an email at 2 pm EST to our distribution list.  The only option I see for the email plug-in is sending out emails when the build fails or the 1st time it's successful after a failed build.  I want Jenkins to send out an email every day at 2 pm EST to let everyone know that a build is occurring.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

A couple of options I can think of:

1. Create a simple job that builds at 2pm EST daily and just prints out a message, then use the [email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) to send out a notification; you can configure this plugin to send email regardless of the build status.  Then trigger the actual build job as a downstream build.
2. Put a shell step in your main build before the actual build happens and make the shell step send the email from the command line.